# md5 hashing on java instead of javascript

Tags: java, javascript, md5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate MD5 hash in Java](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java)

MD5 hash was generated using javascript function. Requriement is to generate the MD5 hash generation in java.

On javaScript side, the password was being passed to str_md5() method of Paul Johnston implementation of MD5. How can this be performed in java?

```
     MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(password.toUpperCase().getBytes());

    byte byteData[] = md.digest();

    //convert the byte to hex format
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++) {
        String hex=Integer.toHexString(0xff & byteData[i]);
        if(hex.length()==1) hexString.append('0');
        hexString.append(hex);
    }

   Javascript
    v_password = jQuery.trim(v_password);
v_userid = jQuery.trim(v_userid);
var v_digest = str_md5(v_password.toUpperCase()); // Implementation in java?
var v_pswdDigest = hex_md5(v_digest + v_userid.toUpperCase());
return v_pswdDigest;
```

Comment: You can use a search engine, such as google, to search for how to apply the `md5` hash in Java. Otherwise, please include in your question [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: Yes please include what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

The [MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class can be used to generate hashes, including MD5 hashes

Comment: How can we obtain the same hash that is being generated using javascript code? If the hash does not match, the user login fails.

Comment: @user1978406, if you're hashing passwords client side, and using `md5` as your hashing algorithm, you're doing authentication ***very very wrong***.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same encoding on both sides.  UTF-8 is a good rule of thumb.